# Не работает fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я подумал возможно этот метод убрали в новой версии jQuery 3.1.1, но подключив старую версию 1.11.0 всё равно не происходит плавного появления. В чём дело?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').text('Ля-ля').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background: black;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Прежде чем объект появился, его надо скрыть.

```
$('#block').hide().fadeIn();
```

Если объект изначально виден, анимация пропускается.

```js
$('#block').hide().fadeIn();
```

```css
#block {
    background:#000;
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="block">
  text
</div>
```

Comment: Всё, всё решено мама я г... Можно закрывать

Comment: Наш сайт отличается от социальных сетей. Он помогает решать прикладные задачи. Поэтому мы используем комментарии только по делу — уточнить проблему, дать конструктивную критику или добавить полезную информацию.

Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers